# React state gets updated but not re-render in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-state

I'm using React Native and I have a custom hook called `useNightMode`. There is a state in my custom hook as following:

```js
const [isInNightModeHours, setIsInNightModeHours] = useState(false)
```

In a root component (AppWrapper), I use this custom hook as following just to see re-renders:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('AppWrapper ', isInNightModeHours)
}, [isInNightModeHours])
```

If I update my state directly from the custom hook, this will be re-rendered. But I need to update it from a component as following. **My component:**

```js
const updateBrigthnessIfNeeded = () => {
  updateIsInNightModeHours(true)
}
```

And this is my App.tsx to see how we are using AppWrapper:

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
  <LocalizationProvider>
    <NavigationContainer onReady={onNavigationReady} ref={navigationRef}>
      <PlatformStatusBar hidden={true} />
      <AppWrapper>
        <AppNavigator />
      </AppWrapper>
      <ApiEnvText API_ENV={API_ENV} />
      <SyncState syncing={syncing} />
      <AppError />
    </NavigationContainer>
  </LocalizationProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

In this case, AppWrapper doesn't get re-rendered. Any idea?

Comment: There's some missing pieces that make this hard or impossible to answer right now. How are you using `useNightMode` in both instances?

Comment: If you are calling the hook in both places (instead of passing down the setter) it's going to create a new state for each hook call. To have a global state that is shared across hook calls, without needing to pass the value and setter as props, you'd need to add context

Comment: @BrianThompson I am simply doing this: `const { isInNightModeHours } = useNightMode()` in both.  That makes sense that they are creating different instances, but how to handle it? What do you mean by adding "context"?

Comment: It's a bit too big of a topic to answer here either as a comment or answer. I would recommend reading about React Context [here](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). With this pattern, you'd put your state hook in the context provider, and pass it's value and setter (if needed) as the context value. Then instead of `useNightMode` creating a new state instance, it would simply return the global instance from context

Comment: @BrianThompson Oh yeah, I know about react context. But I feel I need to use my store instead of Context API, what do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by store? Like a redux store?

Comment: Please post a complete, reproducible, minimal example in a codesandbox. It's impossible to tell what's going wrong as is.

Comment: @BrianThompson We are using zustand store